# How to import python packages while using it in node.js application in VS code

Tags: python, node.js, visual-studio-code, python-venv, pynput

I am developing a quiz application in node.js. I need some python script to keep log of user,so I want to use key logger to keep monitoring the user while attempting the quiz.
Here is the python keylogger script:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging

log_directory = r"G:/Pythonin Node/Keylogger/key_logger/public/log_files/"

logging.basicConfig(filename = (log_directory+"keylog.txt"), level = logging.DEBUG)

def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))

with Listener(on_press = on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Script working well when i run it in pycharm.but when I call it from node application using python-shell I found an error:

```
{
traceback: "Traceback (most recent call last): File "script.py", line 1, in <module> from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput' ",
executable: "py",
options: null,
script: "script.py",
args: [
"xyz",
"abc"
],
exitCode: 1
}
```

This is the simple json response.

Here is my node code:

```
app.get('/', callD_alembert);

function callD_alembert(req, res) {
    var x="xyz";
    var y="abc";
    
  var options = {
    args:
    [
      x,
      y
    ]
  }
  PythonShell.run('./script.py', options, function (err, data) {
    if (err) res.send(err);
    res.send(data.toString())
  });
}
```

python shell executes the simple python script in which I don't use any external package.but when I to use "pynput" package and want to import it.it gives the following error:

[image]

Here is also running a python interpreter:
[image]

please help me to solve this issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are running the python interpreter in different environments.

Try adding the code below to your python script, and run it from pycharm and using PythonShell:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

If the printed paths are different, try modifying the options you pass to PythonShell, so that the path matches the one you have while running the script via pycharm:

```
var options = {
  // replace this with the path you got by running the script in pycharm
  pythonPath: 'path/to/python',
  args:
  [
    x,
    y
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. yes both shows different path know I changed it but I still facing the error: Unable to import 'pynput.keyboard'.  How to install this package in my script in VS-Code

Comment: this package is working well in pycharm but when I try to execute it using python-shell in node app it throw the error: Unable to import 'pynput.keyboard'.